# msc_cntr_0_txt, asp.net charting: unauthorized access error occurs sporadically

Tags: .net, charts

MVC .NET 4.0 application is using Charting component and sporadically I get an unauthorized access error - the key word is sporadically.

web.config entry is as follows
`<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\Temp\AspNetCharting\;deleteAfterServicing=false;" />`

I was looking at other storage modes, i.e. memory or session, but file mode should work and I'm not quite sure why this fails for the same user and the same chart sporadically.

Answer (score 1):

I found posts of some other people on message boards claiming that using

```
chart1.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation
```

in the `Page_Load` event solved their problem.

Comment: could this unauthorized access be happening because when a worker process is writing msc_cntr_0_txt another worker process is attempting to access msc_cntr_0_txt. I'm a little hesitant to recommending a solution to my team without knowing what fixed the issue...